# I get datetimes with SQL but my if-else statement doesn't work

Tags: sql, datetime, if-statement

Using if else statements with datetime I get datetimes correctly, but my if else statement doesn't work I have my code below.

```
[1]DECLARE @systemdatetime datetime
SET @systemdatetime=GETDATE()
PRINT @systemdatetime

DECLARE @Tarihvardiya1 datetime
DECLARE @time time
SET @Tarihvardiya1 = convert(date,GETDATE(),120)
SET @Tarihvardiya1=@Tarihvardiya1
PRINT @Tarihvardiya1

DECLARE @Tarihvardiya2 datetime
SET @Tarihvardiya2 = convert(date,GETDATE(),120)
SET @time = '08:00:00'
SET @Tarihvardiya2=@Tarihvardiya2+CAST(@time AS datetime)
PRINT @Tarihvardiya2

DECLARE @Tarihvardiya3 datetime
SET @Tarihvardiya3 = convert(date,GETDATE(),120)
SET @time = '16:00:00'
SET @Tarihvardiya3=@Tarihvardiya3+CAST(@time AS datetime)
PRINT @Tarihvardiya3


/* VARDİYA 1*/
IF (@systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya2 AND @Tarihvardiya3)
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 1'
INSERT INTO snap_table(stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih) SELECT stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih FROM stok_durumu WHERE @systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya2 AND @Tarihvardiya3
END

/* VARDİYA 2*/
ELSE IF (@systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya3 AND @Tarihvardiya1)
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 2'
INSERT INTO snap_table(stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih) SELECT stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih FROM stok_durumu WHERE @systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya3 AND @Tarihvardiya1
END

/* VARDİYA 3*/
ELSE IF(@systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya1 AND @Tarihvardiya2)
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 3'
INSERT INTO snap_table(stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih) SELECT stok_id,birim_id,Urun_Ismi,Urun_Kodu,Adet,Birim,Tarih FROM stok_durumu WHERE @systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya1 AND @Tarihvardiya2
END

ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'emre'
END
```

Output:

```
Oct  2 2020  5:41PM
Oct  2 2020 12:00AM
Oct  2 2020  8:00AM
Oct  2 2020  4:00PM
emre
```

Comment: Your `vardiya 2` timeblock is setup wrong.  It goes from 4PM to 12AM.  That like saying between 4PM and 3PM.  You can't do that.  It should go from 4PM to 11:59:59 PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do

```
DECLARE @systemdatetime datetime
SET @systemdatetime=GETDATE()
PRINT @systemdatetime

DECLARE @time time
DECLARE @Tarihvardiya1  datetime
SET @Tarihvardiya1  = convert(date,GETDATE())
SET @time = '08:00:00'
SET @Tarihvardiya1 =@Tarihvardiya1 +CAST(@time AS datetime)
PRINT @Tarihvardiya1 

DECLARE @Tarihvardiya2 datetime
SET @Tarihvardiya2 = convert(date,GETDATE())
SET @time = '16:00:00'
SET @Tarihvardiya2=@Tarihvardiya2+CAST(@time AS datetime)
PRINT @Tarihvardiya2


/* VARDİYA 1*/
IF (@systemdatetime <= @Tarihvardiya1 )
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 1'
END

/* VARDİYA 2*/
ELSE IF (@systemdatetime BETWEEN @Tarihvardiya1  AND @Tarihvardiya2)
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 2'
END

/* VARDİYA 3*/
ELSE IF(@systemdatetime >= @Tarihvardiya2)
BEGIN
print 'vardiya 3'
END

ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'emre'
END
```

Comment: your code also works but i had to change values in if statement thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Well that's kinda weird but when i reopened sql management studio and then execute my sql query and it worked it seems there is no problem with my sql query